# ahref tag button insert data into database

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a form that will insert a data into database but not using button submit. instead, an ahref tag that styled to use as a button. And i can't get the right code for it. here is my code:
html:

```
<form name="eventform" id="eventform" method="get">
    <p> Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required
                      pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ,.)(*!?|<>:]{5,80}"
                      title="Please enter valid title of you event."/></p>
    <p> Where: <input type="text" name="place" id="place" required
                      pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ,.)(*!?|<>:]{5,100}"/></p>
    <p>When: <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required/></p>
    <p>People Involved: <input type="text" name="people" id="people" required
                               pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ,.)(*!?|<>:]{5,100}"/></p>
    <p>Content:</p>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" required name="content"></textarea>
    <a href="events.php" id="btnend">Cancel</a>
    <a href="events.php?/add-event/success" id="btnfinish"
       name="btnfinish">Done</a>
</form>
```

php:

```
if (isset($_GET['eventform'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $place = $_POST['place'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $people = $_POST['people'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $object->addEvent($title, $place, $date, $people, $content);
}
```

php in other file:

```
<?php
class Dbother
{
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $dbname = 'pcnl';
    private $conn = '';

    function connect()
    {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect(
            $this->host, $this->user, $this->password
        ) or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($this->dbname, $this->conn) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    //end of connect
    function addEvent($title, $place, $date, $people, $content)
    {
        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO tbl_event
            VALUES
                ('$title', '$place', '$date', '$people', '$content', null, null, null)
        ";
        mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_close();
    }//end of academic
```

Comment: I mean what do expect? can you submit a form without submit button? why cant you style the submit input tag instead?

Comment: Like @meda said, you can't easily submit a form with a link unless you use some javascript.  In that case you can use ajax which is what I recommend.  You should really just style your link unless I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: ahh im sorry for that, im just thinking if it is possible. okay at least i know now :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should just style the input tag

```
<form name="eventform" id="eventform" method="get" action="events.php?/add-event/success">
        <p> Title:          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ,.)(*!?|<>:]{5,80}" title="Please enter valid title of you event."/></p>
        <p> Where:      <input type="text" name="place" id="place" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ,.)(*!?|<>:]{5,100}"/></p>
        <p>When:            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required /></p>
        <p>People Involved: <input type="text" name="people" id="people" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ,.)(*!?|<>:]{5,100}"/></p>
        <p>Content:</p>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" required name="content"></textarea>    
        <a href="events.php" id="btnend">Cancel</a>
        <input id="btnfinish" type="submit" value="Done">
 </form>
```

PS: you could submit form programtically but you don't have to

Comment: Thank you so much @meda, i will take your advice :D

Comment: You can also use a `<button type="submit">` if you want to be able to put things inside it other than straight text.